# java.lang.NullPointerException IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I'm trying to start a service in a different app that's installed on the device. I get a NullPointerException when using startService

```
    public void notConnected(){
        Log.i(TAG,"no connection... reconnecting.");
        Intent reset = new Intent("com.famoco.intent.action.TOGGLE_DATA");
        Log.i(TAG,"calling " + reset.getAction());
        if(reset.getAction().equals("com.famoco.intent.action.TOGGLE_DATA"))
        {
            startService(reset);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"couldn't start service");
        }
}
```

and this is error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[MyAppCommService]
              Process: com.myapppackage.MyApp, PID: 8583
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:494)
                  at com.myapppackage.MyApplocation.activity.MyAppActivity.notConnected(MyAppActivity.java:591)
                  at com.myapppackage.MyApplocation.api.MyAppApi.submitClock(MyAppApi.java:228)
                  at com.myapppackage.MyApplocation.service.MyAppCommService.submitTags(MyAppCommService.java:52)
                  at com.myapppackage.MyApplocation.service.MyAppCommService.onHandleIntent(MyAppCommService.java:98)
                  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Turns out my context returned null, I fixed it by getting the context in onCreate and calling myContext.startservice.

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: What code do you need?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you need to specify your service like this:

`startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by returning context in the `onCreate()` and then calling `context.startService()`

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a new [Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). And looking at that Google example, looks like you use the wrong method to start it up.

```
- you use:
startService(reset);

- try this one:
startActivity(intent);
```

But that starts an Activity. And you want an service. I don't think you can do that **unless you are the developer of that other app**. In general, Android Apps don't have access each others code & resources.